# Are refresh token still valid even if they are not stored in a database anymore?

Tags: access-token, refresh-token, jwt

Lets put on this situation.

- User logs in, he gets a refresh token and an access token
- Access token expires, user gets a new one by refreshing it, and the refresh token in the database assigned to the user is overwritten by a new one.
- The old refresh token, is now not stored in the database, but is it still valid? Since the expire date is in 7 days.

If an attacker managed to get access to that refreshtoken, will he still be able to generate new access tokens by verifying it with the refresh? I guess he needs to obtain the secret for this anyway.

Is a solution to avoid this simply checking if the refreshtoken is assigned to an user in the database during the refreshing proccess?

Comment: Depends on how you define your process I would say.

Comment: "If an user managed to get access to that refreshtoken..."